# Get top records by latest date in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a table like this:

[image]

Assume there are lots of Names (i.e., E,F,G,H,I etc.,) and their respective Date and Produced Items in this table. It's a massive table, so I'd want to write an optimised query.

In this, I want to query the latest A,B,C,D records.

I was using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Name IN ('A','B','C','D') ORDER BY c.Date DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 4
```

But the problem with this query is, since I'm ordering by Date, the latest 4 records I'm getting are:

[image]

I want to get this result:

[image]

Please help me in modifying the query. Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic for the column Produced Items? I am not able to find any relation between input and output data for produced items.

Comment: Please edit your data and expected/actual results to be properly formatted text, not images of text - see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important. Aside from that: have you tried incorporating `GROUP BY` into your query?